Principal Variation Search (PVS) for playing Connect Four in Java
This time, I have an implementation of PVS (Principal Variation Search) algorithm for playing the game of Connect Four.
The repository holding the above .java file contains also a benchmark that plays Connect Four between PVS and Alpha-beta pruning.
The code
com.github.coderodde.game.connect4.impl.ConnectFourPrincipalVariationSearchEngine.java:
package com.github.coderodde.game.connect4.impl;

import com.github.coderodde.game.connect4.ConnectFourBoard;
import com.github.coderodde.game.zerosum.AbstractConnectFourSearchEngine;
import com.github.coderodde.game.zerosum.HeuristicFunction;
import com.github.coderodde.game.zerosum.PlayerType;

/**
 * This class implements the PVS (Principal Variation Search) algorithm for 
 * playing Connect Four.
 * 
 * @version 1.0.0 (Jun 18, 2024)
 * @since 1.0.0 (Jun 18, 2024)
 */
public final class ConnectFourPrincipalVariationSearchEngine 
        extends AbstractConnectFourSearchEngine {

    private final HeuristicFunction<ConnectFourBoard> heuristicFunction;
    
    public ConnectFourPrincipalVariationSearchEngine(
            final HeuristicFunction<ConnectFourBoard> heuristicFunction) {
        
        this.heuristicFunction = heuristicFunction;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ConnectFourBoard search(final ConnectFourBoard root, 
                                   final int depth, 
                                   final PlayerType playerType) {
        return pvsRoot(root,
                       depth,
                       Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
                       Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
                       playerType == PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER ?
                                  -1 :
                                  +1);
    }
    
    private ConnectFourBoard pvsRoot(final ConnectFourBoard root,
                                     final int depth,
                                     double alpha,
                                     double beta,
                                     final int color) {
        
        double value = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;   
        ConnectFourBoard bestMoveState = null;
        
        for (final int x : PLIES) {
            if (!root.makePly(
                    x,
                    color == 1 ?
                            PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER : 
                            PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER)) {
                
                continue;
            }
            
            final double score = -pvs(root, 
                                      depth - 1, 
                                      -beta,
                                      -alpha,
                                      -color);
            
            if (value < score) {
                value = score;
                bestMoveState = new ConnectFourBoard(root);
            }

            root.unmakePly(x);
            
            alpha = Math.max(alpha, value);
            
            if (alpha >= beta) {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        return bestMoveState;
    }
    
    private double pvs(final ConnectFourBoard root,
                       final int depth,
                       double alpha,
                       double beta,
                       final int color) {
        
        if (depth == 0 || root.isTerminal()) {
            return color * heuristicFunction.evaluate(root, depth);
        }
        
        boolean isFirstState = true;
        
        for (final int x : PLIES) {
            if (!root.makePly(
                    x, 
                    color == 1 ? 
                            PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER : 
                            PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER)) {
                continue;
            }
            
            double score;
            
            if (isFirstState) {
                isFirstState = false;
                    
                score = -pvs(root,
                             depth - 1,
                             -beta,
                             -alpha,
                             -color);
            } else {
                score = -pvs(root,
                             depth -1,
                             -alpha - 1, 
                             -alpha,
                             -color);
                
                if (alpha < score && score < beta) {
                    score = -pvs(root, 
                                 depth - 1, 
                                 -beta, 
                                 -alpha, 
                                 -color);
                }
            }
            
            root.unmakePly(x);
            
            alpha = Math.max(alpha, score);
            
            if (alpha >= beta) {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        return alpha;
    }
}

Typical output
AlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine in 5366 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
ConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine in 273 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
ParallelConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine in 1879 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
ConnectFourPrincipalVariationSearchEngine in 144 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
ConnectFourNegamaxSearchEngine in 152 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

<<< ConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine vs. ConnectFourPrincipalVariationSearchEngine >>>
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
ConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine depth:   9
ConnectFourPrincipalVariationSearchEngine depth:  9
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 171 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 119 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 392 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 99 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|.|X|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 561 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|.|X|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 528 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 1442 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 672 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|X|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 146 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|X|O|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 131 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|X|O|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 28 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|X|O|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 48 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 34 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 75 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 56 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|.|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 93 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 146 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 28 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|X|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 58 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|X|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 12 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|X|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 16 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|O|X|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|.|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 1 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|O|X|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|X|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 3 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|X|X|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|O|X|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|X|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 0 milliseconds.
|.|.|X|X|X|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|O|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|O|X|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|X|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Alpha-beta pruning engine (X) in 0 milliseconds.
|.|.|X|X|X|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|O|O|.|
|.|.|O|O|O|X|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|O|.|
|.|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|X|.|O|X|X|X|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PVS engine (O) in 0 milliseconds.
RESULT: PVS engine wins.
Negamax engine in total 3053 milliseconds.
PVS engine in total 1806 milliseconds.

Critique request
As always, I would love to hear any comments on my work.
